# Different definitions of ruled surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces

Let $X$ be a projective smooth surface. I read two different definitions of $X$ to be a ruled surface, namely:

1. $X$ is birational equivalent to some $B\times \mathbb P^1$, where $B$ is projective smooth curve.
2. Through every point on $X$ there exists a projective line. (I am a little confused about this: this means $X$ is already embedded into some $\mathbb P^n$? or means through every point there exists some curve which $\cong \mathbb P^1$?)

I want to know are these two definitions equivalent?

Comment: Actually this means given any point $p\in X$, there exists a non-constant (birational) morphism from $\mathbb{P}^1\to X$, whose image contains $p$.

Comment: @Mohan Is there any difference between this and "through every point there exists some curve isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1$"? If some curve birational to $\mathbb P^1$ then it has to be isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1$.

Comment: Singular curves are allowed.